# Is it possible with GIT ignore a single file from one ORIGIN and not in others ORIGINs

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitignore

I have a project with GIT Repository with 2 different ORIGINs in 2 different servers and I need to launch a pipeline only in 1 server and not in both.

So I like to push the CI script file only in SERVER1 and not in SERVER2, it is possible to manage .gitignore or something like that to push the script only in ORIGIN1 and not in ORIGIN2 ?

Comment: "remotes".  A git repository can have multiple remotes associated with it.  By default, the name "origin" is given to the remote that is added when you use clone.  You can have multiple remotes, but only one (or zero) of them may be called "origin".

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. You can only push commits, and commits never change.

If you don't want the pipeline to run on one server, disable CI on that server. It's a question about GitHub/GitLab configuration, not about Git.

Answer (score 1):

If you have divergent .gitignore file you have two softwares. I think a better solution could consider an'environment variable that can be different in each server. This env variable can enable or disable (for example) the execution of CI script. Is this helpful?